# display fixed decimals in ggplot's annotate

Tags: r, ggplot2, printf, string-formatting, annotate

I need to have all floating numbers in an annotation in `ggplot` to show 3 digits after the decimal separator. but I'm facing this problem:

```
require(ggplot2)
data(iris)
a <- 1.8
b <- 0.9

ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Length, Petal.Length))+
   geom_point()+
   annotate("text", 7, 3, 
            label = paste0("y == ", format(a, digits = 3, nsmall = 3), " %*%z^", 
                           format(b, digits = 3, nsmall = 3)), parse = TRUE)
ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Length, Petal.Length))+
 geom_point()+
 annotate("text", 7, 3,
          label = sprintf("y == %0.3f %%*%%z^ %0.3f", a,b), parse = TRUE)
```

both produce plots with only one decimal. It's clear that if I change to `parse = FALSE`, then the plot comes with the correct number of decimals, but its format is (quite obviously) far from the expected one.

Other than hard-introducing the text, what other options do exist to achieve this?

Comment: This seems to be caused by the `plotmath` rules: `plot(1, 1, main = parse(text = sprintf("y == %0.3f %%*%%z^ %0.3f", a,b)))` also removes the trailing digits.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It works if you add quotation marks to the numbers.

```
ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Length, Petal.Length))+
  geom_point()+
  annotate("text", 7, 3, label = sprintf("y == '%0.3f' %%*%%z^ '%0.3f'", a,b), parse = TRUE)
```

Here, I changed `%0.3f` to `'%0.3f'` resulting in the string

```
[1] "y == '1.800' %*%z^ '0.900'"
```

Due to this, the numbers are no longer interpreted as numercial values. While `1.800` represents the number 1.8, `'1.800'` represents the string `1.800`.

[image]

Comment: Why it does not work with negative numbers? I am getting this error `Error in `annotate()`:
! Problem while converting geom to grob.
ℹ Error occurred in the 3rd layer.
Caused by error in `parse()`:
! <text>:1:20: unexpected string constant
1: y == '+0.461'*x^{2}'-0.300'`